# ArcGIS attribute tables exploitation

Tags: arcmap, attribute-table, attribute-joins, table, database

I have kind of the same question as "greyline" : [How to implement 3NF (third normal form) in ArcGIS attribute tables?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131249/how-to-implement-3nf-third-normal-form-in-arcgis-attribute-tables)

I need, among other things, to place foreign key in my tables to combine them and I don't know how to do it with ArcGIS. 
I tried at first with "New -> Relationship Class" but I didn't have control on my attributes to select properly and avoid redundant data (I don't know the equivalent of "distinct" in ArcGIS commands).
I am now trying to create a model that could combine the tables, but I don't know how to specify that each row for my "Date-t" tab, has to be linked to a single proper table in my database?

My model's structure:
[image]

"Make Table View" details:
[image]

"Add join" details:

[image]

I am ready to change all the method if mine is wrong. I just cannot use the PostGIS since I don't have it.

The aim of this operation is to be able to fetch data from my tables using Python, but I think it's an other question.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the method finally; I found out that relational databases are not the most adequate and appropriate solution on ArcGIS (in my case at least).
I created a large table combining the data of all my previous tables (with `arcpy.Merge_management()`) and added the dates with the `arcpy.AddField_management()`.
It's much easier and it's feasible in one python script.

The fetch data, a simple `arcpy.da.SearchCursor()` does the trick !